# How to delete a key from table using CDbMigration

Tags: php, mysql, yii, foreign-keys, database-migration

This is a structure of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `company_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_info` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Index_1` (`id`),
 KEY `FK_Reference_4` (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci
```

I need to change it, using CDbMigration in Yii 1.x. Currently, key `FK_Reference_4` (`company_id`) is a foreign key to `id` in table `company`. I'm trying to:

- delete old foreing key,
- add new one to another table (`users`).

When im trying to execute migration, using `yiic migration`, it is failing on command:

```
$this->dropForeignKey('FK_Reference_4','company_info');
```

with following error:

```
Exception: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL
statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of '.\focuserv\
company_info' to '.\focuserv\#sql2-1b0-18' (errno: 152). The SQL statement execu
ted was: ALTER TABLE `company_info` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_Reference_4` (E:\IDEs\w
amp\www\focuserv\focuserv\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:358)
```

So `dropForeignKey` is failing. How should I fix or workaround this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of your create table sql statement above it doesn't look like your `FK_Reference_4` is a foreign key it looks like a normal index. Try changing

```
$this->dropForeignKey('FK_Reference_4','company_info');
```

to

```
$this->dropIndex('FK_Reference_4','company_info');
```

FYI a foreign key sql statement looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `company_info` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Reference_4` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) 
REFERENCES `company` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: @PitcPitchinnate , thank you, dropIndex works. Its looks like powerdesigner didnt make constraint but i did with  <code> $this->addForeignKey('FK_'.$FKTableName.'_to_'.$refTable, $FKTableName, $FKColumnName, $refTable, $refColumn);</code> and results: <code>CREATE TABLE `company_info` ( ..........
  KEY `FK_company_info_to_users` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_company_info_to_users` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) .....</code>